# Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. *ngFor is not working on ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework

Code:

[image]

Working for the first time:

[image]

Showing error after refreshing the page:

[image]

Can anyone can help on this?
`BrowserModule` is imported in `app.module.ts` and `CommonModule` is imported in child module.
It is a tabbed application

Comment: show your HTML code please

Comment: <div *ngFor="let str of strings">
    {{str}}
  </div>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please start off by taking the [tour] and then read [ask]. Please then [edit] your question and add all of your code and error messages as properly formatted text, so that people can help you.